# Get All the Posts Records For Specific Category Using Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

I have a table called `Posts`. The table contains some fields and a column called `Category_id`, which is foreign key and data type. All stored as `JSON`. Each `Posts` table has also multiple `categories`. For example, A `News Post` has *'Breaking News'*, *'State News'*, etc.

I stored the `categories` IDs as `JSON` in the column `Category_ID`. Now, I want to fetch all the posts which belong to one specific category.

Example Image:

[image]

From the above image, I would like to fetch all the `Posts` for the `category_id = 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereJsonContains`

For example :

```
Post::whereJsonContains('category_id', '3')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Category model

```
public function posts(){
   return Post::whereJsonContains('category_id', $this->attributes['id'])->with('category')->get();
}
```

And in controller

```
$category = Category::find(1);
$category->posts();
```

But, the best way for such structure is to have a laravel [many to many relation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)